# Cut-off function multiplied by Lipschitz continuous function in the Schwartz space

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, derivatives

In "An SPDE Model for systemic risk with endogeneous contagion" they claim

Let

- $\varphi_\lambda\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}, [0,1])$ a standard cut-off function, which is equal to one inside an interval $[-\lambda, \lambda]$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$,
- $\psi\in\text{Lip}(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. a Lipschitz continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$),

then $\Gamma_\lambda:=\varphi_\lambda \psi\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$ (which is the Schwartz space).

How do I show, that this holds, i.e. the function $\Gamma_\lambda$ is smooth, and fullfills the property

$\forall \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{N}_0:\;\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|x^\alpha D^\beta(\Gamma_\lambda(x))|<\infty.$

$\psi$ as a Lipschitz continuous function doesn't have to be smooth.

Comment: Are you assuming that the cut-off function is Schwartz? That seems to be necessary. And furthermore usually a cut-off function means that $\varphi_\lambda(x) \equiv 0$ for all $x$ outside some bounded set

Comment: Every smooth function with compact support is a Schwartz function (the set of those functions is even dense in the Schwartz space). Also, compact support means, that $\varphi_\lambda\equiv 0$ outside of an compact set (in $\mathbb{R}$ there exists a real number c such that compact sets are subsets of $[-c,c]$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't read closely enough

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused too; here's my attempt at a counterexample. Suppose $\psi = |x-1|$, which is Lipschitz, and $\phi_\lambda$ is some bump function supported on $[-\lambda,\lambda]$ where $\lambda > 1$. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\psi \phi_\lambda) &= \phi_\lambda \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x-1}{|x-1|}  ) + \text{other terms} \\
\end{align*}
But $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x-1}{|x-1|} = \delta_{\{1\}}$ is the Dirac delta at $1$, which is not Schwartz.

The paper does note that the authors

"are mainly interested in the case $\psi = \text{Id}$, other applications may call for a general Lipschitz function, so we allow for this in the ensuing argument"

Perhaps this will be of use, although maybe there's an error in my counterexample

Comment: I will talk to my professor about this, would be interesting to know how they come to this conclusion. One possible explanation (which could be used in the proves I was looking at) is, that Lipschitz continuous functions are weakly differentiable.